# Sorting JXTable with SwingX

Tags: java, swingx, jxtable

I am using `JXTable` which is from SwingX components. If I use `setSortable(boolean flag)` method then it will enable or disable sorting for all columns.

As of my requirement I want to disable sorting for a few columns and enable sorting for other columns.

Can anyone help achieve this functionality?

---

Thanks for your reply. Can you help me with using `setSorterClass(String sorterClassName)` to disable sorting for one column? Could you give me any code examplex? It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4):

SwingX supports a per-column sortable property on the level of the TableColumnExt. It's default value is true, to disable it after column creation

```
table.getColumnExt(myColumnIndex).setSortable(false)
```

Or at creation time, use a custom ColumnFactory, like

```
ColumnFactory factory = new ColumnFactory() {

    @Override
    public void configureTableColumn(TableModel model, TableColumnExt column) {
        super.configureTableColumn(model, column);
        if (... your condition to disable sortable) {
            column.setSortable(false);
        } 
    }
} 
table.setColumnFactory(factory);
table.setModel(model);
```

JXTable will take care of synchronizing the column property to the sorter, provided it is of type SortController (which is the default)

Comment: +1 Very well explained and presented how to do it. Thanks for correcting/updating me. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think, at least according to what I have found on the net you can achieve it by setting 
`setSorterClass(null)` for that column.

As we can read on [the cached web site](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3askS4vVRvBB0J%3aswinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=4%20JXTable%20sorting%20on%20single%20column&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&source=www.google.co.uk), as swinglabs tutorial page appears to be down, I bet it has something to do with the recent mess on the java.net service.
*"JXTables have column sorting turned on by default. You can disable all column sorting using setSortingEnabled(boolean allowSort). You can also disable sorting on a single column by using setSorterClass(String sorterClassName) with a null sorter class name."*

Personally, I think there is no point to block user from sorting on a selected table column. Anyway if a user wants to sort a column he/she should be able to do so, in the end I believe it is better to allow a user for more then less, of course when it goes to such details as what he/she can control in his/hers view.

Comment: agreed with "there is no point to block user from sorting on a selected table column" +1

Comment: that's outdated (or more precise: no longer existing as of 1.6 ;-) api.

Comment: @kleopatra interestning. I was not aware of this fact. And I couldn't find a better answer manily because of the difficulty of using the web page being the result of java.net migration (more like devastation to me :)) of projects. What would you suggest instead, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at [TableRowSorter API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) and see whether JXTable supports it like:

```
TableModel myModel = createMyTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(myModel);
table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(myModel));
```

TableRowSorter has an API method [isSortable()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#isSortable%28int%29):

> public boolean isSortable(int column)
>
> Returns true if the specified column
>   is sortable; otherwise, false.
>
> Parameters: column - the column to
>   check sorting for, in terms of the
>   underlying model
>
> Returns: true if the
>   column is sortable

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you help to know how can I use setSorterClass(String sorterClassName) for disable sorting for one column. Can you give any code example. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: -1 for spreading a not-swingx'ish approach. There's no obligation to answer if you don't know SwingX/JXTable ;-)